# Find and mark duplicates in HTML Table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a **dynamically generated HTML table**. It varies not only the pure content, but also the column names from case to case.

But one thing is in common between all the tables that may arise - there is **one, two or all three of the following column names**:

***Vorname*** (first name), **Nachname** (last name), **Name** (name)

Now I would like to examine these columns for duplicates. There are, however, a chain that I want to try to follow, clearly demonstrate:

"Check all the values ​​in the column *first name, last name, name*. If one or two of the column do not exist, it can be ignored, and to work with the  existing column or columns (for example, only first name and last name).

Are duplicate entries found in the column, these lines get the CSS property 'background-color: yellow ;.

But duplicate values ​​should only be recognized as such when first and last name of the line are the same or even first name and name. Depending on which columns exist.

A small example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Mc Doe</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

-> Since only the first  (In this example, the first name column) matches (John), but the second column (*Last Name or name*) is different, is not to be recognized as a duplicate row.

Unfortunately, I'm still not so fit in JavaScript / jQuery, so I need some help from the experts =)

Comment: Since you generate the table dynamically you should better prevent the duplicates during the generation. It doesn't make sense putting entries in the table and later removing them on the client side.

Comment: Well this is true, but unfortunately I have no control about the table that's going to be created. I just see that I forgot an information. The table is created with PHP, which reads an .xls file. And the duplicates shouldn't be removed, just highlighted with the yellow background-color. It is important to display the .xls file as an html table without any modification to its data. :-)

Answer (score 1):

use $.inArray() it will return -1 if found. you should prob treat `name` such as do a trim of whitespace, make all lowercase, so it will be compare properly.

```js
var allName = []; 
var dupicateName = []; 

$('td').each(
  function(index, el) {
    var name = $(el).text();
    if(jQuery.inArray(name, allName)===-1) {
      allName.push(name);
    } else {
      dupicateName.push(name);
    }    
  }
);

console.log(dupicateName);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Mc Doe</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<hr/>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```js
function highlightDuplicateRows(selector) {
    var index = {},
    getText = function () {
        return $.trim( $(this).text() );
    };
    $(selector).find("tr").each(function (tr) {
        var rowKey = $(this).find("td").map(getText).toArray().join("|");
        if (index.hasOwnProperty(rowKey)) {
            index[rowKey].push(this);
        } else {
            index[rowKey] = [this];
        }
    });
    $.each(index, function (rowKey, rows) {
        $(rows).toggleClass("highlight", rows.length > 1);
    });
}

highlightDuplicateRows("#test");
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Mc Doe</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, it is "kind of working"... the only thing that is missing is the fact, that the table should only be checked for duplicate values in the columns "Vorname", "Nachname" or "Name". Because there are other columns that have the same values, but they shouldn't be checked for duplicate values. And like I said , in some tables that are being generated, there may be just one, two or all three of the columns that matter.